# watchMedia (or innerWidth?) as a mediaQuery for showing div

Tags: javascript

the plan is to make two sliders. One with graphic for desktop and the second one for mobile. It's SAAS, so im not able to touch html. Tried with css but there's no nth-of-class-type similar stuff.

The HTML:

```
<div class="top row">
<div class="container">
    <div class="box box-slider" id="box_slider_4">

    </div>

    <div class="box box-slider" id="box_slider_36">

    </div>


</div>
```

This is my main idea, but it's "static". The code hide / show the div but only when running from mobile -> desktop or back. It's not working right after loading, so mobile got two sliders until the mediaquery goes to more than 767px. The 767px width is the place where is the breakpoint for me.

```
 const WindowCheck = window.matchMedia('(min-width: 768px)')
  const sliderDiv = document.getElementsByClassName('box-slider');


  function handleTabletChange(e) {
      // Check if the media query is true
      if (e.matches) {
        sliderDiv[0].style.display = "none";
        sliderDiv[1].style.display = "block";
      } else {
        sliderDiv[1].style.display = "block";
        sliderDiv[0].style.display = "none";
      }

  }

  // Register event listener
  WindowCheck.addListener(handleTabletChange);

  // Initial check
  handleTabletChange(WindowCheck);
```

Any idea how to make it more complex and unbreakable, so user wont see two sliders at one time?

Comment: That should work fine like that, your initial call should take care of the load case. Now if you are really only hiding one of these elements, a CSS @media rule would be a lot more cleaner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's working, but as i learned later on -> only when i refresh the page. The workaround are event listeners, but the question and answer got working code.